# CNTK: ->Forward or ->Evaluate crash on some PCs, not on others

Tags: c++, cntk

I am evaluating various neural networks created with CNTK from C++.   Some are essentially AlexNet, others are V3-inception.

Everything runs fine on dozens and dozens of PCs.  But I have found two PCs on which the same code will crash when attempting to evaluate the AlexNet model -- but the V3-inception model will always work - even on these two 'problem PCs'.

So, I figure it must be something about these 2 PCs -- some prerequisites missing, or something.  I have checked the obvious things (like vc_redist… )

Going crazy!  What could it be?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On one of the PCs, I finally tracked down a Microsoft DLL ( msvcr120.dll ) that apparently was corrupt -- because I replaced it with the same version (pulled off another PC) and then everything worked!   However, on malfunctioning PC#2 this same fix did not help.  So, its still weird...